# look for aqadmcli.exe to delete messags in the exchange 2003

Tags: exchange-2003

I have many messages in the different queue. [Some useful articles](http://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/show/267-how-to-clean-all-email-queues-at-once) said, using the aqadmcli.exe can help me, but the download url is not public access.

> ftp://ftp.microsoft.com/pss/Tools/Exchange%20Support%20Tools/Aqadmcli/aqadmcli.exe

[image: how to login the ftp?]

How do I access it, or anybody has its md5sum, or some hash digest ? I find another unofficial download url, but no one can tell me. Is it valid?

> http://files.bluecrow.net/microsoft/pss/Tools/Exchange%20Support%20Tools/Aqadmcli/

---

finally, I download it. its md5hex is 55535495df5e1ef0613c7a287987c200

Comment: The first URL works just fine for downloading the utility. What problem are you having accessing it, exactly?

Comment: @joeqwerty it ask me to login. I have no idea what is the username and password.

Comment: Hmmm... that's interesting. It wasn't prompting for authentication when I posted my comment.

Comment: Can you download it before ?

Comment: I can download it now

Comment: @joeqwerty could you make a verification answer, I can mark it as solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first URL works just fine for downloading the utility.

Comment: Thanks for your test. I found it not always downloadable. If anyone need download it from other source. Its md5hex is 55535495df5e1ef0613c7a287987c200